# Counterexample to: if $1\le p<q<\infty$, then $L^q(X)\subset L^p(X)$ with $\mu(X)=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

We know if $\mu(X)<\infty$, and if $1\le p<q<\infty$, then $L^q(X)\subset L^p(X)$ (can be proved by using Holder's inequality).

Is this still true if $\mu(X)=\infty$? Counterexample?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try some negative powers of $x$ on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: So we have $1/x\in L^2([1,\infty))$ but is not in $L^1([1,\infty))$. Am I correct? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.